# Metamask: wallet_addEthereumChain is not working when using polygon mainet but works with polygon mumbai

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, polygon

Im trying to programmatically switch the metamask network of the user. Using [`wallet_addEthereumChain`](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#other-rpc-methods)

It's working fine when requesting a network change for Polygon mumbai,
however it doesn't work when using `Polygon Mainet`, and I get : `Chain ID returned by RPC URL https://polygon-rpc.com does not match 0x137`

If I add manually the network on metamask, using the same information it works.

- This code above is working, for polygon mumbai

```js
const { ethereum } = window;
 await ethereum.request({
                id: 1,
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
                params: [
                  {
                    chainId: "0x13881",
                    rpcUrls: ["https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com"],
                    chainName: "Polygon Testnet Mumbai",
                    nativeCurrency: {
                      name: "tMATIC",
                      symbol: "tMATIC", // 2-6 characters long
                      decimals: 18,
                    },
                    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/"],
                  },
                ],
              });
```

- this one doesn't work and gives me : Chain ID returned by RPC URL https://polygon-rpc.com does not match 0x137'

```js
const { ethereum } = window;
await ethereum.request({
                  id: 1,
                  jsonrpc: "2.0",
                  method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
                  params: [
                    {
                      chainId: "0x137",
                      rpcUrls:[  "https://polygon-rpc.com"],

                      chainName: "Polygon Mainnet",
                      nativeCurrency: {
                        name: "MATIC",
                        symbol: "MATIC", // 2-6 characters long
                        decimals: 18,
                      },
                      blockExplorerUrls: ["https://polygonscan.com/"],
                    },
                  ],
                });
```

- Here is a screenshoot of what the user is supposing to get on his metamask wallet when i fire the request.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to convert to hex the chainId with web3.utils.toHex() function:

```
chainId = '137'; chainId = web3.utils.toHex(chainId);

chainData = [{
    chainId: chainId,
    chainName: 'Matic(Polygon) Mainnet',
    nativeCurrency: { name: 'MATIC', symbol: 'MATIC', decimals: 18 },
    rpcUrls: ['https://polygon-rpc.com'],
    blockExplorerUrls: ['https://www.polygonscan.com'],
}];
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! You saved me some headaches...

Answer (score 3):

```
import { utils } from 'ethers';

const networkMap = {
  POLYGON_MAINNET: {
    chainId: utils.hexValue(137), // '0x89'
    chainName: "Matic(Polygon) Mainnet", 
    nativeCurrency: { name: "MATIC", symbol: "MATIC", decimals: 18 },
    rpcUrls: ["https://polygon-rpc.com"],
    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://www.polygonscan.com/"],
  },
  MUMBAI_TESTNET: {
    chainId: utils.hexValue(80001), // '0x13881'
    chainName: "Matic(Polygon) Mumbai Testnet",
    nativeCurrency: { name: "tMATIC", symbol: "tMATIC", decimals: 18 },
    rpcUrls: ["https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com"],
    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/"],
  },
};


await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
    params: [networkMap.MUMBAI_TESTNET],
});
```